# How to copy cells from one workbook to another based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I will try to explain my problem as clear as possible. There is a workbook (lets named it antennalist) with one sheet. This sheet contains a list of antennas - column antenna names, column frequency and columns with parameters of the antennas. The other workbook contains also one worksheet. In this worksheet (let it be rawdata) have columns info3 which corresponds to antenna names and columns with frequency and other columns too. I need a code which will check if the value/text in info3 and frequency (workbook rawdata) is the same as value/text in antenna name and frequency (workbook antennalist), then to copy the parameters (which are in the gray columns) which corresponds to the antenna name and frequency to the corresponding columns (marked in red) in the other workbook. The columns are not sequentially and the column frequency in workbook rawdata are variable. It will be good to check the frequency only the first symbol -if is 9 (900), or 1 (1800), or 2 (2100). I have no idea how to do it.... I appreciate the help with this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmZbx.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tPB9.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Added to what @Pᴇʜ said, this question has been asked a lot, only this week. You could use the browser and get lots of answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's **NOT** the code **BUT** some guidelines:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim LastRow1, LastRow2 As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, Position As Range, cell As Range

    'Set the two workbooks. Keep in mind that code will works only if you have both workbooks open
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("antennalist.xls")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("rawdata.xls")

    'Let us assume that data appears in Sheet1 & Column A in both workbooks. Find the last row of column A in both Sheets to create our ranges
    With wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = .Range("A" & LastRow1)
    End With
    With wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng2 = .Range("A" & LastRow2)
    End With

    'Loop rawdata workbook,Sheet 1 & column A and check:
    ' 1.If the values of rawdata workbook,Sheet 1 & column A appears also in antennalist workbook,Sheet 1 & column A
    ' 2.If the value next to them match also (this is for testing purposes so you must change)
    For Each cell In rng2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, cell.Value) > 0 And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = .Range("B" & rng1.Row).Value Then
        'If condition met copy from rawdata & paste to antennalist
            wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2").Copy wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A2")
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the guideline! I will try it and see what will happen.